# Insert pojo to database with spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have a pojo that I want to insert into a database (Sql Server). When I run my code, I'm getting a "the conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported". My question is, if my pojo and my database have everything named the same, can I just write it directly like this (or are there maybe annotations that'd let me do that)? Or do I always need a bean in here to do the mapping? I'm thinking this error might be because I'm jamming a pojo in where it doesn't belong.

In my main class I have

```
@Inject
TradePersistenceService dataService;

Trade trade = new Trade();
trade.setSec_id(-1);
trade.setSourceload_id(-1);
trade.setCusip("123");

dataService.insertTradeMessage(trade);
```

And in my spring configuration I have

```
<integration:channel id="InsertTradeMessageRequestChannel" />
<integration:channel id="InsertTradeMessageReplyChannel" />

<integration:gateway id="RTService"
    service-interface="com.whatever.TradePersistenceService">
    <integration:method name="insertTradeMessage"
        request-channel="InsertTradeMessageRequestChannel" reply-channel="InsertTradeMessageReplyChannel" />
</integration:gateway>

<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway request-channel="InsertTradeMessageRequestChannel"
    query="insert into MSRB_RTRS (Sec_ID, SourceLoad_ID, CUSIP) values (:Sec_ID, :SourceLoad_ID, :CUSIP"
    data-source="rmsa">
</int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>
```

In the database, I have a table called MSRB_RTRS with two numeric columns, and a varchar.

Finally, my pojo (with the standard getters and setters omitted here to reduce clutter)

```
public class Trade {
int sec_id;
int sourceload_id;
String cusip;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to use `update`, not `query`, for `INSERT`.
Second it isn't clear how that `Sec_ID` is related to the `sec_id` property in the `Trade` class.

You should consider to use something like:

```
<beans:bean id="parameterSourceFactory" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory">
    <beans:property name="parameterExpressions">
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="Sec_ID" value="payload.sec_id" />
            <beans:entry key="SourceLoad_ID" value="payload.sourceload_id" />
        </beans:map>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

You can find more info in the [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-outbound-channel-adapter):

> In the example above, messages arriving on the channel labelled input have a payload of a map with key foo, so the [] operator dereferences that value from the map. The headers are also accessed as a map.

Comment: Okay, so whatever I pass in will be referred to as "payload" in the xml. That clears things up, thank you!

Comment: Does spring integration not support any kind of annotations on the pojo (such as you'd have if you were serializing a pojo to xml)? I haven't been able to find anything, but I figured I'd ask.

Comment: Well, there is no. Spring Integration JDBC is fully based on the existing Spring JDBC module. Since there latest one doesn't provide any annotations mapping, the former does that as well. If you need some ORM, take a look into Spring Integration JPA.

Comment: Hey Artem, last question. I am using your code and the gateway is throwing an error, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'handler' cannot be null. Any idea what that means?

Comment: That's not related to the JDBC arguments process. You should inject that `parameterSourceFactory` into the `<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway ` as a `update-sql-parameter-source-factory`